# omit certain pages from history cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, history

I am using this script to store the user's history to a cookie for the last 10 pages accessed. So far I've got the script displaying the cookie data using the document.title, and url in a list.

My question is what would be the simplest way to add a page skip feature, that would let me omit certain pages from being added to the history cookie? Everything I've tried hasn't worked, as it's a little bit outside of my knowledge.

Thanks for your time and help.

JS:

```
(function($){

var history;

function getHistory() {
    var tmp = $.cookie("history");
    if (tmp===undefined || tmp===null) tmp = "";
    if ($.trim(tmp)=="") tmp = [];
    else tmp = tmp.split("||");
    history = [];
    $.each(tmp, function(){
        var split = this.split("|");
        history.push({
            title: split[0],
            url: split[1]
        });
    });
}

function saveHistory() {
    var tmp = [];
    $.each(history, function(){
        tmp.push(this.title+"|"+this.url);
    });
    $.cookie("history",tmp.join("||"),{ expires: 60, path: "/" });
}

function addToHistory(title,url) {
    var newHistory = []
    $.each(history, function(){
        if (this.url!=url) newHistory.push(this);
    });
    history = newHistory;
    if (history.length>=10) {
        history.shift();
    }
    history.push({
        title: title,
        url: url
    });
    saveHistory();
    writeHistory();
}

function writeHistory() {
    var list = $("<ul />");
    $.each(history, function() {
        var element = $("<li />");
        var link = $("<a />");
        link.attr("href",this.url);
        link.text(this.title);
        element.append(link);
        list.append(element);
    });
    $("#history").empty().append(list);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    getHistory();
    var url = document.location.href;
    var split = url.split("#");
    var title;
    if (split.length > 1) {
        title = $("#"+split[1]).text();
    } else {
        title = document.title;
    }
    if (title===undefined || title===null || $.trim(title)=="") title = url;
    addToHistory(title,url);
    url = split[0];
    $("a[href^='#']").click(function(){
        var link = $(this);
        var href = link.attr("href");
        var linkUrl = url+href;
        var title = $(href).text();
        if (title===undefined || title===null || $.trim(title)==="") title = linkUrl;
        addToHistory(title,linkUrl);
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="history"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

several ways you could approach this... You could keep an Array of urls not to save, or you could put something in the page that would let the script know not to save that page?...

> function saveHistory(){
>     if ($('.no-save-history')) return false;
>     /*...*/
>   }

HTML:

> < div id="history" class="no-save-history">